# Hyperbola $2x(1-x)=y(1-y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

How can I find real-solution of this Hyperbola

$$2x(1-x)=y(1-y)$$

I found that when $x=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $y=0$ and $y=1$ and also for $x=1$ $\Rightarrow$ $y=0$ and $y=1$

Comment: By solutions, are you referring to the $x$-intercepts? If so, simply substitute $y = 0$ and solve for $x$ as per normal.

Comment: I mean to find center for x and y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-write the equation and complete squares:

$$2x-2x^2=y-y^2\implies -2\left(x-\frac12\right)^2+\frac12+\left(y-\frac12\right)^2-\frac14=0\iff$$

$$8\left(x-\frac12\right)^2-4\left(y-\frac12\right)^2=1$$

and there you have the center.

Answer (score 1):

[GraphHypb](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5B2%20x%20(1-x)%20%3D%3D%20y%20(1-y),%20%7Bx,-1.5,1.5%7D,%7By,-1.5,1.5%7D%5D)

All correct. The hyperbola passes through all the 4 points  $(0,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,0)$ and its center is shifted to the new point $(1/2,1/2).$

Comment: Yeah but I need to know how to find 1/2 and 1/2 ?

Comment: Graph the hyperbola. It looks like openiing up due sign of x,y.Point (1/2,1/2) is not on the curve but at its center.